# Tensor Flow import error on Python 3.5.2 - 64bit Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, tensorflow, pip

I installed tensor flow using pip as follows"

`> C:\Users\Satish>**pip install tensorflow**
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\users\satish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\users\satish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\satish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.1.0 in c:\users\satish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\satish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\satish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in c:\users\satish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in c:\users\satish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in c:\users\satish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow)`

But when I try to test tensor flow installation I get the following error:

`C:\Users\Satish>**python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)"**                                                                             Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                         File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper     return importlib.import_module(mname)                                                                                                                  File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module                                        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import                                                                                           File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load                                                                                        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked                                                                                        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec                                                                                      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module                                                                                File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                           ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                         File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>                        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow                                                                                                        File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>               _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()                                                                                                              File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper     return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')                                                                                                   File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module                                        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                          ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                     File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>                               from tensorflow.python import *                                                                                                                        File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>                        raise ImportError(msg)                                                                                                                               ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                            File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper     return importlib.import_module(mname)                                                                                                                  File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module                                        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import                                                                                           File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load                                                                                        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked                                                                                        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec                                                                                      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module                                                                                File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                           ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                         File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>                        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow                                                                                                        File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>               _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()                                                                                                              File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper     return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')                                                                                                   File "C:\Users\Satish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module                                        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                          ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,                                                                                                 you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;                                                                                       please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter                                                                             from there.`

Any suggestion on how to get tensor flow working based on the above errors ?